# How to debug through a jar file if the remaining code of the application is in .net?

Tags: java, .net

How to debug through a jar file if the remaining code of the application is in .net? entire application is running via Visual studio and its calling methods inside the external jar file. I want to debug through the java code

Comment: You can't debug if you don't have the source code.

Comment: Source code is there

Comment: Can you provide more details ? Debug is a big topic

Comment: How are you running it via Visual Studio at all? How is your .NET code calling Java code? Please give a *lot* more context - this is an unusual situation.

Comment: suppose i have an application in .net which is calling a java applet while running, which is a jar file applet.jar. I want to step through the java code while the application is calling the applet

Comment: i mean when i'm running the application in debug mode in a browser for .net code it should hit in VS and for java code it should hit in eclipse

Comment: Hi running the application Using IISExpress.. and specified the jar name in the .net code and which in turn calls the applet. opened the java source code in eclipse. Set some debug parameters in java runtime  as -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=1044 and created a new  remote debug configuration in eclipse by giving host as local host and port as 1044.. but while debugging it is showing failed to connect to remote VM . connection failed. and the applet is not getting suspended before debug starts. it is running fine. How to resolve this issue